# C++ copy cin into cout directly but in reverse order

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, reverse

Is there is any similar solution to this command:

```
using namespace std;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

-- this command copies everything into cout but I would like to change it to copy the string in reverse order so I have used this:

```
using namespace std;
reverse_copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

-- but this did not even compile. Are there any solutions to this? Thank you

Comment: "copy string in reverse mode" - reverse each string individually, or reverse the order of copying? i.e., "foo bar" => "bar foo" or "oof rab"?

Comment: What does _this did not work well_ mean? What output do you get?

Comment: `reverse_copy` requires a bidirectional iterator, but `istream_iterator` is an input iterator. Maybe read it into some collection first then reverse it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to copy it in reverse directly (without cheating and using a lambda) considering `std::cin` is a **stream**, you'll have to store the input somewhere first and then reverse it.

Comment: If you want to reveres each word instead of the whole input (e.g. "foo bar" becomes "oof rab") then it's not that hard to write your own `ostream_reverse_iterator`. If you want to reverse the order of the word (e.g. "foo bar" becomes "bar foo") then you need some other solution. And if you want to completely reverse the input ("foo bar" becomes "rab oof") that's a third problem. Now, which variant do you want? For some example input, what should the output be? Please clarify!

Comment: Also, in the future "this did not work well" is not a very good problem description. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The first two arguments to [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) must be [Bidirectional Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) whereas [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is [Input Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) which cannot behave as Bidirectional Iterator. That explains why it doesn't work — it wouldn't even compile.

You've to write your own iterator — or do it manually in a loop — to solve this problem (which is not clear as to what mean by *reverse* : given `foo bar` as input, do you want `bar foo` or `oof rab`, or `rab oof`? as many of the commenters say).

Answer (score 2):

You can write a recursive function. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::ostream & reverse_output( std::istream &is = std::cin, 
                               std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    std::string s;

    if ( is >> s ) reverse_output( is, os ) << s << '\n';

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is( "Hello Bobul Mentol" );

    reverse_output( is );
}
```

The program output is

```
Mentol
Bobul
Hello
```

Of course instead of the string stream I used for the demonstrative purpose you can use `std::cin`. In this case the call of the function will look just like

```
    reverse_output();
```

Otherwise you need to store the input in some container and use it to reverse the inputted data for outputing.

For example

```
std::vector<std::string> v( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( std::cin ),
                            std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

std::reverse_copy( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                   std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of some standard algorithm which can copy a reversed collection by an `input_iterator` or even `forward_iterator` - probably if this exist, it requires at least `bidirectional_iterator`.

So, you can use the temporary collection to store the values read, like this:

```
vector<string> tmp;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(tmp));
copy(tmp.rbegin(), tmp.rend(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a general problem here: `std::cin` is a *stream*. When it is attached to a file, you could imagine a way to initially find the size and so how to know where the reverse iterator should start. But when it is attached to a terminal, with an imprevisible human being able to type input data at will, at what position should the reverse iterator start? I have no idea of it, and it looks like `cin` designer had no more - more seriously, `cin` does not propose a reverse iterator, and it is *by design*.

If you want to *present what has been inputted in cin but in reverse order*, you must first specify:

- what is the piece of input to reverse: anything until stream is closed, or anything until first end of line, or [put here your own definition]. Once it's done you have the start place for your reverse iterator
- what is the unit to be reversed: one character or one word at a time. Once this is done, you know what your reverse iterator should return.

The implementation could use a vector of strings. You consistently accumulate words or single characters in it until what you have defined as the end of the stream. Once you hit the end, you hold a container with bidirectional iterators so copying it in reverse order should be easy.